# The time complexity for finding the kth smallest number in a min-heap

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, runtime-analysis, heaps

Suppose that $k < \sqrt n$, what is the time complexity to find the $k_{th}$ smallest number in a min-heap?

I thought that we can remove the root element for k times and each time we apply heapify? So it should be $O(k \log n)$ but the answer is $O (k \log k)$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650917/oklogk-time-algorithm-to-find-kth-smallest-element-from-a-binary-heap

Comment: You did not use all the info from the problem statement.

Comment: Are you allowed to destroy the heap?

Comment: @Raphael yes, I think the link provided in the other comment answers this.

Comment: @xskxzr  Linking [SO] is rarely useful since their perspective is usually quite different from ours.

Comment: @Raphael I think for this specific question, the answers in SO can answer it perfectly...

Answer (score 3):

There is an $O(k)$ algorithm [1].

[1] Frederickson, G. N. (1993). An optimal algorithm for selection in a min-heap. *Information and Computation, 104*(2), 197-214.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an $O(k\log k)$ algorithm at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651139/5376789), slightly improved.

```
Create toVisit, a collection of nodes that contains the nodes which we will traverse next. This is initially just the root node.
Let counter c = 1.
While c < k:
    Remove the smallest node from toVisit
    Insert that node's children in the given min-heap to toVisit
Return the smallest node from to toVisit
```

The `toVisit`  can be implemented in a min-heap or balanced BST/B+ tree or skip list in which the insertion and removal of the smallest node takes $O(\log m)$ time, where $m$ the number of nodes. Assuming the degree of original min-heap is $O(1)$, there were at most $O(k)$ elements in `toVisit` since there have been at most $k$ insertions.